# Android Studio?Toolbar Error

Tags: android, android-studio

This is my appbar_layout.xml. According to how I defined, it should show a bar at the top. But it's now showing in the design tab. Yet, when I run it on my android it shows. What can be the problem?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

My bulid.gradle for the project

```
     // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common 
     to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

[Design Tab Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0SxJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exactly same problem, it seems to be bug in `Android studio 3.1.3`

I downloaded `Android studio 3.3 Canary 3`  and the problem was solved for me.

https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/